# Can't add a script to a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't add the script to my GameObject I don't know why.

it shows like a problem thing and it won't add

```
using UnityEngine.;
using System.Collections;

public class zombieScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //declare the transform of our goal (where the navmesh agent will move towards) and our navmesh agent (in this case our zombie)
    private Transform goal;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        //create references
        goal = Camera.main.transform;
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        //set the navmesh agent's desination equal to the main camera's position (our first person character)
        agent.destination = goal.position;
        //start the walking animation
        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("walk");
    }


    //for this to work both need colliders, one must have rigid body, and the zombie must have is trigger checked.
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        //first disable the zombie's collider so multiple collisions cannot occur
        GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>().enabled = false;
        //destroy the bullet
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
        //stop the zombie from moving forward by setting its destination to it's current position
        agent.destination = gameObject.transform.position;
        //stop the walking animation and play the falling back animation
        GetComponent<Animation>().Stop();
        GetComponent<Animation>().Play("back_fall");
        //destroy this zombie in six seconds.
        Destroy(gameObject, 6);
        //instantiate a new zombie
        GameObject zombie = Instantiate(Resources.Load("zombie", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;

        //set the coordinates for a new vector 3
        float randomX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-12f, 12f);
        float constantY = .01f;
        float randomZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-13f, 13f);
        //set the zombies position equal to these new coordinates
        zombie.transform.position = new Vector3(randomX, constantY, randomZ);

        //if the zombie gets positioned less than or equal to 3 scene units away from the camera we won't be able to shoot it
        //so keep repositioning the zombie until it is greater than 3 scene units away. 
        while (Vector3.Distance(zombie.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.position) <= 3)
        {

            randomX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-12f, 12f);
            randomZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-13f, 13f);

            zombie.transform.position = new Vector3(randomX, constantY, randomZ);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Copy the whole code and create a new script and paste it there and try again, also it'll be helpful to look at log panel when trying to add to see if any errors shows up

Comment: If there is an error/warning message in the Console regarding your script it would really help if you add it to your question. Make sure the script name matches exactly (including letter case) the class name .. in your case the script should be called `zombieScript.cs` and be displayed as `zombieScript` in Unity. Also make sure there are no compiler errors

Comment: What is the problem thing? please specify